# Feeding API parameters to imported ReactJS components in jsx

Tags: reactjs

Below is my reg_form.jsx, it's GenderField has to contain a Select with three options. This options are defined on the backend and send through API. These values are used for backend and frontend validation, so I don't want to duplicate them.

Also I don't want to define all the fields in one file as there suppose to be 30 fields once finished and it would be a huge mess to have them all in reg_form.jsx.

My question is: How do I feed the imported GenderField with values from a API call? Should I do a API call in each component file that requires backend data (that would be some 20 fields=20 API calls?) or is there a way to do one API call and distribute data to the components?

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router';
import Auth from '../../services/AuthService';
import EmailField from '../../components/forms/form_parts/email';
import UserNameField from '../../components/forms/form_parts/username';
import PasswordFields from '../../components/forms/form_parts/password';
import GenderField from '../../components/forms/form_parts/gender';

class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    signup(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var email = this.refs.email.value;
        var username = this.refs.username.value;
        var password1 = this.refs.password1.value;
        var password2 = this.refs.password2.value;
        var gender = this.refs.gender.value;

        Auth.signup(email, username, password1, password2,gender)
            .catch(function(err) {
                alert("There's an error signing up");
                console.log("Error logging in", err);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <form role="form">
                    <GenderField/>
                    <EmailField/>
                    <UserNameField/>
                    <PasswordFields/>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.signup.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
                </form>
                )
            }
}

export default RegistrationForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

One source for the data loading the page makes more sense than a bunch of server calls.

End result could look something like this:

```
let {
  gender, email, userName, passWord
} = this.refs.form;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
var RegistrationForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { data: null };
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result) {
        this.setState({data: JSON.parse(result.initial_data)});
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
render: function () {
      return (
        <Formsy.Form url="/signup">
          <GenderField data={this.state.data}/>
          <UserNameField/>
          <EmailField/>
        </Formsy.Form>
      );
    }
```

})

Important part:

```
<GenderField data={this.state.data}/>
```

and this is the render function of the field:

```
render() {
    var items = this.props.data;

    //console.log(items);
    if (items == null) {
            return (<div>Loading ... </div>)
        }
    else {
        items = items.gender;
        return (
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="gender">{this.label}</label>
                <select defaultValue="" className="form-control" id="gender" ref="gender">
                    {   
                        items.map(function (item) {

                            return <option key={item} value={item[0]}>{item[1]}</option>;
                        })
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
            )
    }
}
```

At first the component renders as "Loading ..." because parents initial state says that data is null. After component is mounted ajax retrieves data from server and rerenders the state, which makes the child rerender but this time data is avaliable and is used to construct html.